# how to program multi pages system in php

Tags: php, sql

I have PHP script and I programmed Topics system 
and I want to show every 10 topics in one page,, How to do that??
sql table:

```
ID
L_TITLE
L_URL
L_COMMENTS
L_VIEWS
L_STATE
```

php code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM LESSONS WHERE L_STATE='0' ORDER BY ID DESC") or die($sql_error);
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $l_id = $rs['ID'];
        $l_title = $rs['L_TITLE'];
        $l_comments = $rs['L_COMMENTS'];
        $l_views = $rs['L_VIEWS'];
    }
}else{
        $l_id = $no_data;
        $l_title = $no_data;
        $l_comments = $no_data;
        $l_views = $no_data;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @JohnConde --> sorry but I am  
beginner I do not know how to do that code

Comment: @njk --> thank you, i will read that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways.

A common way I see is for a page to query the whole database, then store the results into an array. A variable is used to decide how many results per page, and a variable to hold the active page.  You could use GET or POST to manage the current page.

Example:

If you have 100 items, and you wanted to show 10 items per page, you would have 10 pages.
(If you have 91 items, it should show 10 pages as well!)

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM LESSONS WHERE L_STATE='0' ORDER BY ID DESC") or die($sql_error);

//DETERMINE PAGE SIZE/NUMBERS
$currentPage = $_GET["page"];
$itemPerPage = 10;
$itemTotal = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$lastPage = $itemTotal / $itemPerPage + 1; //+1, because you round up to whole pages
$startItem = $currentPage * $itemsPerPage;

if($itemTotal > 0){
    //PUT DATA IN ARRAYS
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $id[] = $rs['ID'];
        $l_title[] = $rs['L_TITLE'];
        $l_comments[] = $rs['L_COMMENTS'];
        $l_views[] = $rs['L_VIEWS'];
    }

    //DETERMINE WHAT PAGE AND ITEMS TO SHOW
    if(0 < $currentPage && $currentPage <= $lastPage){
        for($i=$startItem;$i<=$startItem+$itemsPerPage;$i++){
            //EXIT LOOP IF END OF ITEMS
            if($i > $itemTotal){
                break;
            }
            //DISPLAY DATA
            echo "<table><tr><th>id</th><th>title</th><th>comments</th><th>views</th></tr><tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>" . $id[$i] . "</td><td>" . $l_title[$i] . "</td><td>" . $l_comments[$i] . "</td><td>" . $l_views[$i] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
        //DISPLAY PAGE NUMBERS
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<a href='/?page=0'>|&lt;</a>";
        echo "<a href='/?page=" . $currentPage - 1 . "'>&lt;</a>";
        for($i=0;$i<$lastPage;$i++){
            echo "<a href='/?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
        }
        echo "<a href='/?page=" . $currentPage + 1 . "'>&gt;</a>";
        echo "<a href='/?page=" . $lastPage . "'>&gt;|</a>";
        echo "<br />";
    } else {
        //If invalid page number, send to page 0
        header("Location: /?page=0");
    }
}else{
        $l_id = $no_data;
        $l_title = $no_data;
        $l_comments = $no_data;
        $l_views = $no_data;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use mysql_* functions anymore. They aren't officially depreciated, but they might as well be. Second. I've just glanced over the code for a second but try making those variables in the while loop arrays
i.e

```
$l_id[] = $rs['ID'];
```

Then call $l_id with a foreach loop

EDIT: I guess I'm wrong abotu the mysql_* functions as well, it appears the yare officially depreciated.

Comment: how to use foreach loop??

Comment: you really should try and figure it out on your own, use w3schools, or better yet get a good textbook, but foreach loops loop through an array. So write something like: foreach ($l_id as $id) { echo $id "<br/>"; } and that'll display all of your id's

Comment: I learnt foreach now hhh, but i have a problem i will but it in an new question